# How to change the typeface and font size in the Ask Question textarea

Tags: support, user-interface, font-size

I feel that the typeface used in the Ask Question textarea does not look good, and that the font size there is too small. How can I change them? Can they be changed network-wide by SE?

Comment: Ctrl-Mouse wheel up.

Comment: i mean the font as well . Just like in css

Comment: The text in the textarea gets resized for me in Chrome 13 when I use Ctrl-Plus or Ctrl-Mouse Wheel Up.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the fonts, font size, etc. which is embedded in the editor.

However, you can use a browser extension like [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) for Chrome or Stylish for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome), or the dev tools for either of those browsers, to modify the CSS for your personal preferences.

To correct the size issue more quickly (It's currently a standard 12-point monospace font) hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> to zoom to the default level (in case you've zoomed out).  If that's not sufficient, as Robert Harvey suggested in the comments, zoom in with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Mouse wheel up (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>).